# Ant <junit> task fails on Jenkins due to NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Resources.setCache(Z)V

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, configuration-management, ant-junit

I am running ant  tasks on 1.7.1 version of Ant using ant jenkins plugin. Build fails due to following error -

```
BUILD FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Resources.setCache(Z)V
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.BatchTest.<init>(BatchTest.java:57)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.createBatchTest(JUnitTask.java:556)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$CreateNestedCreator.create(IntrospectionHelper.java:1252)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$Creator.create(IntrospectionHelper.java:1169)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:550)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:346)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:198)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Task:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile-test" description="to run junits">
    <mkdir dir="${build.report}"/>

    <property name="junit.path" refid="junit.class.path"/>
    <!--<echo message="JUnit classpath ==> ${junit.path}"/>-->

    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="no" haltonerror="no" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath refid="junit1.class.path"/>

        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${build.report}">
            <fileset dir="${src.test}">
                <include name="**/Test*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

The same task works fine at my local using same setup (including ant version). Can someone please advise what is the possible root cause here?

Comment: I found that the method setCache() is not avaialble in ant distribution 1.7.1 but in higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Ant 1.7.1 distribution and found there is no such method available.

```
org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Resources.setCache
```

Though this is strange that I am using the same distribution (ant-1.7.1) at my local and it is working fine. I have no other distribution available on my system. Then how it is getting reference of any higher version that contains this method? Is there any implicit dependency resolution happening in case of ant  task is introduced?

**Note:** The Jenkins server is running on a different machine and it is pointing to the same version of ant distribution deployed on that machine.